# При запуске кода выдаёт ошибку: Subquery returns more than 1

Tags: mysql

Код должен отобразить Группу, имя, фамилию, средний балл, количество неаттестованных оценок, количество оценок, которые меньше 4.

```
SELECT
    a.FK_GroupName_ID AS Grupa, 
    CONCAT(a.Name, " ", a.Surname) AS "Audzēkņa vārds, uzvārds",
    AVG(d.Vertejumi) AS "Vidējā atzīme",
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(d.Vertejumi)
    FROM `diploma vertejumi` AS d
    WHERE d.Vertejumi = "n/v"
    GROUP BY d.FK_PerKods_ID) AS "n/v skaits",
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(d.Vertejumi)
    FROM `diploma vertejumi` AS d 
    WHERE d.Vertejumi < 4 
    GROUP BY d.FK_PerKods_ID) AS "Nesekmīgo vertējumu skaits"
FROM audzekni AS a INNER JOIN `diploma vertejumi` AS d ON a.PerKods_ID = d.FK_PerKods_ID
WHERE d.Vertejumi <> "n/v"
GROUP BY d.FK_PerKods_ID;
```

Comment: Один из ваших 2-х подзапросов возвращает более чем 1 строку. Проверьте их и сделайте так, что бы возвращал 1 строку.

Comment: Помоги найти @SwaD

Comment: @SwaD Оба, а не один...

Comment: А что должен вернуть запрос? В нем есть ряд противоречий и странностей... например вы группируете по FK_Period с условием `d.Vertejumi <> "n/v"` при этом в подзапросе ищите `d.Vertejumi = "n/v"` по всей таблице...

Comment: @Akina MySQL нормально реагирует на группировку по полю, которого нет в select? Я уже MySQL подзабыл, знаю что Oracle будет явно ругаться на присутствие в select полей без группировки. Это мне для развития )

Comment: @SwaD *MySQL нормально реагирует на группировку по полю, которого нет в select?* В MySQL есть опционная переменная, значение которой влияет в т.ч. и на допустимость такого отклонения от стандарта. `@@sql_mode`

Comment: @Akina Благодарю

Comment: @SwaD d.Vertejumi <> "n/v" нужно для того, чтобы не включать их в счёт средней оценки, будет правильно, если записать ещё один подзапос:
`
(Select 
AVG(d.Vertejumi) AS "Vidējā atzīme"
From diploma vertejumi as d
Where d.Vertejumi <> n/v
Group by FK_PerKods_ID)`

Comment: Ваши подзапросы внутри select возвращают вам выборку по всей базе сгруппированной по d.FK_PerKods_ID. Попробуйте в ваши подзапросы добавить к where условие `and a.PerKods_ID = d.FK_PerKods_ID`

Comment: @SwaD я понял, что мне не нужно использовать подзапросы, ибо можно просто использовать SUM() с выражением, но теперь не получается вычислить среднее арифметическое, потому что нужно не включать "n/v" в счёт:
`SELECT
 a.FK_GroupName_ID AS Grupa, 
 CONCAT(a.Name, " ", a.Surname) AS "Audzēkņa vārds, uzvārds",
 AVG(d.Vertejumi) AS "Vidējā atzīme",
 SUM(d.Vertejumi = "n/v") AS "n/v skaits",
 SUM(d.Vertejumi < 4 AND d.Vertejumi <> "n/v") AS "Nesekmīgo vertējumu skaits"
FROM audzekni AS a INNER JOIN `diploma vertejumi` AS d ON a.PerKods_ID = d.FK_PerKods_ID
GROUP BY d.FK_PerKods_ID;`

Comment: Воспользуйтесь case. `avg(сase when d.Vertejumi = "n/v" then null else d.Vertejumi end)`. [Подсмотрено тут](https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/6.4.php)

Comment: @SwaD сработало! Спасибо большое!